# preg_match() No ending deliminator found

Tags: php, preg-match

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689825/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-no-ending-delimiter-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445133/no-ending-delimiter-found-error), and [this](http://www.php.net/preg_match), and half a dozen other questions about `preg_match` on SO, and I still can't figure this one out.

I went to use [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/browser-and-os-detection-script) code from a CodeReview question and got an error saying that there was a `preg_match()` no deliminator '/' found.

Can someone help me fix it? The code in question is this statement:

```
if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
```

You can find it by going to the bottom of the new, edited version of the code in the question itself, and counting up approx 12 lines (not counting blank lines).

Comment: What's in `$regex` when the error occurs?

Comment: Haha my you are basicly asking: my regex doesnt work help me! Without saying what you're regex is... lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code posted on Code Review, in the $os_array there is the following line:

```
'/win16'                =>  'Windows 3.11',
```

It is missing the `/i` from the end of the regex on that line, which is probably causing your error. The line above that is also missing the `i` but this won't break anything.

As paxdiablo suggested, printing our your `$regex` variable inside the loop should have found this problem quickly.

Comment: It beats me why somebody is doing browser detection for Windows 3.11 in the first place.

Comment: Good catch. It's not actually in the array the user stated it was in but is in the earlier array. +1.

Comment: @Minitech it's not my code. I'm just a person with a need to detect OS.

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo - I hesitated to post this when your answer popped up, but the OP is looking at the wrong function anyway. @minitech haha, I guess its thorough!

Comment: @minitech: dead right. All those ones ME and below (and possibly 2000) should be relegated to the "unknown OS" category. ME especially, since it was a horrible mistake from MS :-)

Comment: Good catch. I'll comment with the fix the person's code on CodeReview.

Comment: Question reopened. Appending the correction now yields "unknown OS".

Comment: Question reclosed. Added an extra brace during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This is Debugging 101 stuff. Insert a statement immediately after:

```
foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) {
```

to print out the current values of `$regex` and `$value`.

That should (hopefully) show you exactly what it's complaining about.

This should also be done to the earlier array scan, where you would have found the errant `'/win16'`, as picked up by JohnC.

Comment: I took out the browser part because I found it to be very buggy, and I didn't need the detection the original poster on CodeReview needed. That said, I was unable to get the code to echo anything out.