# How preg_match should have been debugged

Tags: php, debugging, preg-match

This question is directly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336658/preg-match-no-ending-deliminator-found) SO question I posed about 15 minutes ago. This is not intended to be a duplicate post of that one, rather hoping this is more of a learning experience.

In the question posed, I was trying to figure out what was causing a preg_match no deliminator found error. The code (which **is not mine**) is available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/browser-and-os-detection-script). The error ended up being a missing '/i' in the Windows 3.11 array.

It is important to note, for the sake of this question, that I **do not** use the browser section.

The first question, and rightfully so, posed what what is the value in $regex. However, I am still unable to find a way to get that value.

What I originally tried was declaring a global variable outside the function, and right before the preg_match line setting the global variable equal to regex. I then attempted to echo the global variable. I was greeted with a blank page.

I should also mention that I had (at the time of asking the original question) removed this code:

```
$user_agent     =   getBrowserOS();
$device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_agent['browser']."<br />    <strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_agent['os_platform']."";
print_r($device_details);
echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");
```

And thus the only thing I should have seen was the value of the global variable. Instead, I saw nothing.

Can someone explain how this should have been debugged?

Edit: As Per John C's Answer

```
<?php
$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
function getOS() { 
global $user_agent;
$os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";
$os_array       =   array(
                        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                        '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                        '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                        '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                        '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                        '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                        '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                        '/win95/'               =>  'Windows 95',
                        '/win16'                =>  'Windows 3.11',
                        '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                        '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                        '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                        '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                        '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                        '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                        '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                        '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                        '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                        '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                    );

foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 
var_dump($regex);
var_dump($value);
    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        $os_platform    =   $value;
    }

}   
return $os_platform;
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo` dumping the variables? PHP is interpreted and it will stop only when it encounters error. At least you can localized the error to some segment of the code. Detecting the exact error is a matter of experience, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh That's what I tried to do, but I didn't get anything back. Added my code showing the echo I made.

Comment: @ChrisMirno I haven't been following the story so may have missed something but a) try using `print_r($var)` instead of `echo` - works better on objects and b) if you get 0-byte output it's usually worth checking the apache error logs as parsing/some other fatal errors just don't get handled by your PHP code

Comment: @ChrisMirno: I don't code PHP (only a little bit in the past), so I don't know the facilities of the language. But the idea is still there. Printing out is the best solution, next to using a debugger, if one is available at all/good enough.

Comment: @Basic thanks for your help. John C made a comment that it will never get to the print/echo statements. I'll look up print_r() (never heard of it before).

Comment: @ChrisMirno `print_r()` is _similar_ to `var_dump()` [see here](http://qualitypoint.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/printr-versus-vardump.html) for a quick comparison. Slight variations in output but fundamentally the same, it's really a matter of personal preference. In fact, I use neither in my code, I've written a small `dump()` function which does some other things around `print_r` (output a stack trace, timestamp, etc and format for HTML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to focus on this instance rather than general debugging, since I'm sure there are better guides to get you started.

**1. Look at the error message.**
Most of the time, PHP isn't too bad at telling you what went wrong and where (within a couple of lines anway). In this instance, the you would have something along the lines of

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /var/www/html/whatever.php on line 36
```

So the problem is a missing slash on line 36. Line 36 ( which falls within `getOS()`):

```
if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
```

We can infer this is a problem with $regex - in this instance a quick look at the array in question shows a missing `/` in one of the lines, but maybe the data is in a database or can't be so easily checked.

**2. Start dumping variables**
If something isn't right, checking in your variables is good start. You want to do this *as close as possible* to your error so you know nothing is happening in between. We know the problem is `$regex` from the above, so immediately above the problem line:

```
var_dump($regex);
if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
```

New result:

```
...
string '/win95/' (length=7)
string '/win16' (length=6)

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /var/www/html/whatever.php on line 36
```

PHP halts as soon as we get the error, so the last dumped line will show the problem variable. Hello, a regex with a missing slash!

**On your approach:**
PHP will halt when it hits an error, which is part of why I suggest dumping variables as close to the problem as possible. In your case, the script never got as far as your echo statements.

**Bonus notes!**

- I prefer `var_dump()` for checking variables because it is better at showing an empty/null variable (echo will just print a blank) plus it handles arrays and objects.
- If you find yourself doing a lot of debugging, have a look at getting [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) running. Immensely useful.

Comment: Ok this makes alot more sense.

Comment: One thing I am confused on is when I add the var_dumps I still get blank PHP file on view. So where/how do I retrieve the var_dumps data?

Comment: var_dump should just push data out like an echo would. Are you dumping before the problem statement?

Comment: Yes. I edited my code from Edit 1 to reflect what I am looking at now.

Comment: var_dump($os_array) also does nothing. This is totally weird.

Comment: Ok this is strange as heck. I don't get var dump results on the page I am dumping, but I do get the dump results in a file where I am calling the getos() function. Shouldn't it be reverse?

Comment: The function only runs when it is called. Since you aren't calling `getos()` in the above page, the code (and therefore your dumps) aren't run :-)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Well I learned alot out of this question. Definitely going to the first place in my Chrome Bookmark bar. I would upvote you but I can't till I get more reputation. Marked as correct answer. Thank you so, so much for your help :)

Comment: No worries mate, best of luck with it